# Metadata Filtering Feature not showing up for Classic Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, metadata-navigation

Metadata navigation configured in classic library added fields to show up in tree view, but Metadata filtering feature is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

When you configuring Metadata Navigation for library, you could configure Key Filter also.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have configured key filter as well, but still search is not enabled.

The problem is with one site collection, If I do same configuration in another sitecollection it is working. I am not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Could it be that somebody disabled the feature?

Comment: "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" Feature is activated, but still Key Filters search not enabled at library level.